# How to make navigation centered, spreaded and and scales with screen size

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navigation, nav

I`m making a portfolio website using bootstrap for my layout , however all is good except that I want to make the top navigation scales and keeps centered (each item takes a percentage of the width equally) on all devices.
(something like apple.com)

this is my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

  <head>
    <link data-require="bootstrap@3.3.7" data-semver="3.3.7" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
        <script data-require="jquery@2.2.4" data-semver="2.2.4" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="bootstrap@3.3.7" data-semver="3.3.7" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="header">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
          <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" id="navbarToggle" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsable-nav" aria-expanded="false">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
              <a class="navbar-brand" ui-sref="app" style="padding:0 0 0 10px;">
                <img alt="Brand" class="img-responsive" src="image url here" />
              </a>
          </div>
          <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsable-nav">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li ui-sref-active="active">
                <a ui-sref="home" class="first">Home                                                                        <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li ui-sref-active="active">
                <a ui-sref="projects">Projects</a>
              </li>
              <li ui-sref-active="active">
                <a ui-sref="about">About</a>
              </li>
              <li ui-sref-active="active">
                <a ui-sref="contact">Contact</a>
              </li>
              <li ui-sref-active="active">
                <a ui-sref="awards">Awards</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container-fluid -->
      </nav>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

this my style:

```
.navbar-brand > img {
    width: auto;
    height: 44px;
    max-width: 100%;
    min-width: 60px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 5px;
}

ul.navbar-nav {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: justify;
}
ul.navbar-nav > li {
  margin: 0 auto;
  content: '';
  max-width: 100;
  width: auto;
  display: inline-block;
} 
ul.navbar-nav > li > a {
  margin: 0 auto;
  content: '';
  max-width: 100;
  width: auto;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

And here is my plunker editor:

https://plnkr.co/edit/bXOx4mwzdbFwEYRtdNd6?p=preview

And here is my plunker full screen (just easier for you to test and change screen size)

https://run.plnkr.co/ZPgTeuYZA2LYl7Et/

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the top navigation scales: there is instruction in the basic template of Bootstrap docs:

> Copy the HTML below to begin working with a minimal Bootstrap document:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
```

add `float:none` to `ul.navbar-nav` and change`width: 19%;` to `ul.navbar-nav > li`:

```
.navbar-brand > img {
    width: auto;
    height: 44px;
    max-width: 100%;
    min-width: 60px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 5px;
}

ul.navbar-nav {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
  float: none;
}
ul.navbar-nav > li {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 100;
  width: 19%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

I removed `ul.navbar-nav > li > a` which doesn't affects to neither items order nor common markup.

Comment: ok Banzy, Thak you.. i could manage the scaling but i need each item to occuby a portion of the page equally on all sizes.

Comment: 've changed answer

Comment: Great, as this answer shopuld help others too,  can u please try to remove the dublicated styles from the > li (s)and the > l i> a (s), and can u plz tell me what properties should be assigned to each as this is a matter of confusion